# 'javascript:close()' doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, window

I'm really new to JavaScript, but I think this should be pretty simple. I'm just trying to create a link to close my window using: document.write("Close this window");

However, when I click the link created by the above code nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? my entire code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Loops demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openActor() {
            actorWin = window.open("","actorWin","height=200,width=600,resizable");
            actorWin.document.write("<!doctype html>");
            actorWin.document.write("<html lang=\"en\">");
            actorWin.document.write("<head>");
            actorWin.document.write("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
            actorWin.document.write("<title>Keira Knightley</title>");;
            actorWin.document.write("</head>");
            actorWin.document.write("<body>");        
            actorWin.document.write("Info on, one of the great actors of our time.");        
            actorWin.document.write("</body>");
            actorWin.document.write("</html>");
      }


   function Movie(title, actor, web1, web2) {
    this.title = title;
    this.actor = actor;
    this.link = web1;
    this.link2 = web2;
}
var movie1 = new Movie('Pride and Prejudice', 'Keira Knightley', 'http://movies.yahoo.com/movie/pride-and-        prejudice-2005/','http://keiraknightleyfan.com/');


document.write(movie1.title + '<blockquote>“A lady\'s imagination is very rapid; it jumps from admiration to love,     from love to matrimony in a moment.” ― Jane Austen, Pride and Prejudice</blockquote>');
document.write('<a href="javascript:var movieWin = window.open(\'',movie1.link, ' \'     ,\'movieWin\',\'height=500,width=500,resizable,top=200,left=400\')">Read more about Pride Prejudice</a><br>');
document.write("<a href='javascript:openActor()'>Click here for info on the lead actor</a><br>");
document.write("<a href='javascript:close()'>Close this window</a>");

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using document.write, since this will overwrite anything else in the page.

Comment: @Lee Taylor: It will only overwrite the contents of the document when the document has already been closed, in this case it's still open, so there is no problem when he uses write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function named `close`.
`javascript:close();` simply calls the function `close`.
If you want to close the popup window, you will need to call close on that.
Like: `javascript:actorWin.close();`

In that case, make sure you declare the `actorWin` in the global scope (put `var actorWin;` just above `function openActor...`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close windows by using `close()` when they haven't been opened via javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.close()`

```
document.write("<a href='javascript:window.close()'>Close this window</a>");
```